# Tap detection using accelerometer sensor in android phone

Tags: android

I make some App about 'Tap detection using Accelerometer sensor'.

It is not using 'onTouchListener' in Android.

So, can I ask some hint or advice?

Comment: May Help [link](http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.in/2013/06/tap-detection-supported-by-gyroscope.html) !

Comment: Thank you! it is good information! I'm understand that information, but difficult. Can I get or find sample code?

Comment: @maveňツ Finally!!! I success Tap detection!!!Using Accelerometer and Gyroscope. Thank you very much~ ^_^

Comment: I know this is old... But in case the questioner has any solution it would be good to post it here as an answer. Mainly because I am interested in it, and on the other hand to close another StackOverflow question properly!