# How to detect tapping on the phone's backside?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, accelerometer, gyroscope

I would like to detect user tapping on the device's back, NOT screen
Since users cannot touch the screen wearing VR headset.
It would be great if I can use JS for this, neither android studio or swift IOS is fine too.
Kindly, share your ideas.
This is one of the ideas: http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.kr/2013/06/tap-detection-supported-by-gyroscope.html

Thanks

Comment: you means device back of hardware surface ?

Comment: you mean like just a general tap, or like know where the user is tapping on the back? the former you might be able to detect via the accelerometer, but i would think it would give too many false positives to be of any real use

Comment: You should process data from accelerometer. Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10877432/6950238) answer.

Comment: Yeah it is like link(http://www.knocktounlock.com). when users put thier phone into the VR cardbord or glass they cannot touch or tap  screen.  Yes guys I need to use gyroscope or accelerometer

Comment: @AndriyOmelchenko Yes exactly. So I am expecting someone who processed the data (maybe using pattern things which i dont know well)

Answer (score 0):

If there are no sensors for that, so it is not directly possible. Some devices have fingerprint sensors on the back, but those are small and not directly accessible from the code.

You could try calculating this using the gyrometer, but it would not be too accurate I fear.

Comment: yeah you are right. I am just trying to use gyrometer and acceloremeter. too accurate is no need. it is just for clicking in VR.

Comment: You would need dedicated hardware to detect this accurately

Comment: What kinda dedicated hardware u mean?

Comment: Basically a phone with touchable back ^^ Or maybe a special phone armor :)

Comment: Yeah but I just wanna use normal phone which has accelometer and gyroscope :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26858538/tap-detection-using-accelerometer-sensor-in-android-phone#comment42357791_26858538 This guy succeeded, but no sample shared

Comment: There is a link in the first comment, about how to calculate taps. Try that maybe, but seems to be a lot of work :-(

Comment: Yeah it is, that's why I am looking for someone who did it already :)